# Runtime application

Tags: node.js, heroku, runtime, telegram

Can I use heroku for nodejs application, which must be running always? Now I want create telegram bot without webhook and it must be running always.

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = 'MY TELEGRAM BOT KEY';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    // send a message to the chat acknowledging receipt of their message
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Received your message');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Deploying and running Node.js apps on Heroku is much easier than we think. You can find a guide about realtime Node.js app on Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

You have to use a paid plan to run realtime apps. As we know the free Heroku Dyno will sleep after 30 mins of inactivity. While we access our app after being inactive we have to wait for a couple of seconds to get back to the active stage. More details about Heroku plans and pricing can be found [here](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)

PS: As I am a beginner please don't stop with my answer. You can wait for answers from expert StackOverflow users they are yet to come. Or if you would like, open a ticket on Heroku support and ask your queries there